# Unknown error for Python in Maya

Tags: python

## User Interface Window

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class UserInterface():
    def __init__(self):
        
        windowID = "myWindowID"
        
        if cmds.window(windowID, exists = True):
            cmds.deleteUI(windowID)
        
        cmds.window(windowID, title="User Interface", sizeable=False, resizetoFitChildren=True)    
        cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns=3,columnWidth=[(1,75), (2,60), (3,60)], columnOffset=[(1,"right",3)]
        
cmds.showWindow()
```

I'm working on a basic UI for Maya in Python however a minute ago this code was working, now all of a sudden it says # Error: invalid syntax #

Any help on this please

Comment: PLease, copy and paste the error message verbatim in the question.

Comment: # Error: invalid syntax #

Answer (score 0):

Your last line doesn't close the brackets for

```
    rowColumnLayout()
```

Comment: After adding the bracket at the end it now displays this
#Error: No window found"

Answer (score 0):

got it to work

had to add

cmds.showWindow("myWindowID")

Thank you everyone